# Video should touch top and bottom of box

Tags: css, html

I have a piece of code here that shows a video in a green box which is for a website I'm developing. The source obviously wouldn't work so I've just replaced it with 'xxxxxx'.

The problem is that there is a small space underneath the video where the box is too big.

For some reason the box isn't flush with the video.

The sides of the video are purposefully not touching the edges but I wanted the bottom and top of the video to touch the box.

I'm sure it can't be too complicated and it's probably something simple that I've missed.

If you need any more info just ask.

Thanks guys.

```html
<div style="background-color:#B9CFBB" align="middle">
      <video width="360" height="240" controls>
          <source src="xxxxxx">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the video to scale correctly, you have to expand the sides in order to expand the height aswell.

Comment: @MarcHjorth I've have tried this but the space between the bottom of the video and the box only moves making the box bigger as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing the height to `200px` and adding `display: block` will work. Like this one

```html
<div style="background-color:#B9CFBB" align="middle">
<video controls style="width:360px;height:200px;display:block;" preload="metadata">
  <source src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm#t=0" 
          type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  <source src="devstories.mp4" 
          type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />

</video>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the 200 pixel height. This is only because the inline snippet view at SO is only that high

Comment: i think not. See my pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYawpM?editors=1010

Comment: Just ditch the height altogether. `video` is an inline replaced element. It knows it's height automatically if you just give the width. https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/YMNPpB?editors=1000

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra Thank you, is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You should give the video `display: block;` style

```css
video {
  /* video has a default display of inline */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#B9CFBB" align="middle">
      <video width="360" height="240" controls>
          <source src="xxxxxx">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
</div>
```

This is because an inline element is display in line with surrounding text content. This may be empty in this case, but it has a line-height: As the default `vertical-align` of `video` is `baseline`, the descenders need room, too. That is where the gap  comes from.

You could change the vertical-align as well of video like illustrated below (I added text to demonstrate the issue.) to solve the issue.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
video {
  /* video has a default display of inline */
  display: inline;
}

#two video {
  /* video has a default vertical-align of baseline */
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
#three video {
  vertical-align: -3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" style="background-color:#B9CFBB">
fghpq before <video width="360" height="240" controls>
           <source src="xxxxxx">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video> after fghpq 
</div>

<div id="two" style="background-color:#F9CFBB">
      fghpq before <video width="360" height="240" controls>
          <source src="xxxxxx">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video> after fghpq 
</div>

<div id="three" style="background-color:#B9CFFB">
      fghpq before <video width="360" height="240" controls>
          <source src="xxxxxx">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video> after fghpq 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works on here. But how do I incorporate the "display: block;" bit into the code?

Comment: @ReedPrice What do you mean? Do you know, how to write style sheet file and use them with <`link>` ?

Answer (score -1):

Use display:block as style for video element, it will solve your problem.

```
video {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Don't just copy other answers